# ASP.Net window control library not a ControlAxSourcingSite

Tags: c#, asp.net, object

I'm new in ASP.Net. 
Recently I tried to create a window control library and to use it in aspx web page but it seem like cannot recognize as user control in the page.
I tried to use the user control from the sample web site "http:// www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052604-1.aspx" and it work!
Then when i try to debug and notice the different:

Sample user control from www.4guysfromrolla.com:
[WinControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd07u.png)
. The user control i created:
[objtest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd07u.png)
My user control appear as {Object} instead of {ControlAxSourcingSite}. 
and when i alert the parameter it only show me "undefined".

I'm not sure what am I missing or do wrong. I try to find out why but end up no clue...not even Google can help. It's really frustrated.

Hope there are some one can help me.

Sorry if I'm for asking stupid question.

sample code in aspx:

```
<object id="objtest" height="0" width="0" classid="uscControl/uscTest.dll#uscTest.uscTest" VIEWASTEXT>
    <param name="Response" value="test" />
</object>

<object id="MyWinControl1" height="200" width="240" classid="uscControl/WinControls.dll#WinControls.WinTreeview" VIEWASTEXT>
    <param name="sCode" value="My Code1"/>
</object>
```

to call:

```
<input type="button" value="CallTest" onclick="CallTest();" />
...
function CallTest() {
      alert(window.document.getElementById("objtest").Response);
      alert(window.document.getElementById("MyWinControl1").sCode);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks God..finally i found out the answer by myself.
The main cause is when I create the window control library I did not modify the "AssemblyInfor.cs" to set [assembly: ComVisible(**true**)]. This is the main cause the object return undefined in aspx.

Hope it help the others as well :)